# OpenGL, offscreen hard shadows calculation with stencil

Tags: opengl, shadow, projection, stencil-buffer, off-screen

I am trying to figure it out if and how would be possible to calculate hard shadows from multiple light-sources off-screen.

preamble: scene is very complex, up to several million of triangles, up to hundred different light-sources, lights, material and depth enabled and maximum precision (at least 10kx10k pixel ground resolution). Shadows are nothing else than planar projected shadow, that is I am rendering the objects themselves by pre-multiplying by a shadow matrix (given a light-source position and a plane). Multiple objects, multiple light-sources but just a single plane.

For this reason real-time is impossible. Also impossible is to think about an incremental stencil value, since I have only one byte (255 useful values) and I may have more than 255 light-sources.

Therefore my idea was to render off-screen (to texture or render-buffer image).

For each light source, I calculate my shadow matrix and apply it. Then I render my first object with a specific stencil number (i.e. 1). Then I render my second object. I need to render it only where the stencil number is 1 **and** I need to zero all the other pixels, because I am interested in the hard shadow only. Then the third object and so on. 
At the end I repeat all the process for the second light source and so on.

Is it possible? Better texture or render-buffer image? Once hard shadow is calculated I need to retrieve it back on the cpu to analyze it and render it also on the ground in my scene.

Ideally I would need only the stencil buffer attached to my FBO but they say [here](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Framebuffer_Object_Examples#Color_texture.2C_Depth_texture):

> Stencil
>   NEVER EVER MAKE A STENCIL buffer. All GPUs and all drivers do not support an independent stencil buffer. If you need a stencil buffer, then you need to make a Depth=24, Stencil=8 buffer, also called D24S8. Please search for the example about GL_EXT_packed_depth_stencil on this page.

Is this still valid today?

Looking around, I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7570215/opengl-es-stencil-operations) a way of zeroing all the other pixels by render a full screen polygon between each object, but I wonder if there is anything more efficient..?

Comment: You can never be sure of anything. Driver vendors sometimes interpret the standard their own way. Test and see.

Comment: I can do it, but the program need to run also on some other computers (not old) so I would need to have somehow a basic security about that.
However my major issue is to find a way to zero the stencil value of all the other pixels...